# No me funciona el método get en html

Tags: html, html5

Soy principiante y estoy intentando hacer que cuando envío el formulario me envíe a la otra pagina, pero cuando le doy al botón de enviar no pasa nada. alguien me podría ayudar, que tengo que cambiar o añadir

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Mi pagina web</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/formulario" method="POST"> 
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
        <br>
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
        <br>
        <label for="Comentario">Comentario</form></label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="Igrese un comentario"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <h1>Esta es mi primera pagina web donde contaré sobre mi vida</h1>
    <h2>Esto se tratara sobre historias de mi vida</h2>
    <p>En esta biografia hablaré de muchas facetas de mi vida donde pasaré por muchos momentos buenos y malos</p>
    <hr>
    <h2>Mi infancia</h2>
    <p>Todo empezó cuando recién tenia 5 años, <span style="color:blue">era un niño feliz y divertido,</span> que se la pasaba <br>
         divirtiendose con sus jugetes</p>
    <!-- Este comentario hablaré como hice mi codigo, lo hice facilmente con unos videos de youtube aprendiendo autonomamente en mi habitación-->
    <a target="_blanck" href="https://www.google.com">Ir a mi instagram</a> <br>
    <img src="Foticos/enrabiao.jpg"  width="300" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: en el action del form tienes indicado una carpeta "/formulario", sin extension. Entiendo que quieres mandarla a una nueva pagina, pero es ahi donde tienes que indicarla, y solo es una carpeta...

Comment: y como puedo poner las extensiones?

Comment: si tu pagina se llama, por ej: comentarios.php, pues... eso es lo que tienes que poner. algo tipo: `<form action="comentarios.php">`

Comment: lo intenté como me dijiste, pero tampoco me sirve:(, ayudaa dsdkjsds

Comment: El *action* tiene que indicar un fichero que pueda procesar el servidor o una URL de destino. Tu botón de *submit* no tiene valor, puedes usar: <input type="submit" value="Enviar">. Esta sintaxis no es HTML5: `<input type="submit" />`, me refiero al cierre. Un botón de *submit* alternativo sería `<button type="submit">Enviar</button>`. Por el título de la pregunta "No me funciona el método get en html", infiero que el método de tu formulario es incorrecto, estas enviado por POST, tendrías que indicar `method="GET"`.

Comment: puedes decirnos como se llama la pagina a la que quieres que redirija el formulario?

Comment: @Jakala, me gustaría enviarlo a otra página que quiero crear

Comment: ustedes me podrían ayudar vía discord?

Comment: crea la pagina de destino nueva, ponle el nombre que quieres, y dinoslo... asi te podemos indicar algo mas aproximado el mensaje

Comment: Que tienes en la ruta /formulario ?

Comment: Tienes varios errores: 1) Tu pregunta, aunque ambigua en tu explicación, es **no me funciona el método GET**, y lo tienes puesto como POST. 2) ¿Nadie se ha dado cuenta que hay dos `</form>` y por eso no le funciona el boton `submit`? 3) De paso corrige el `_blanck`  por `_blank`.  4) ¿Tu instagram es google? 5) Crea la otra página y sustituye `/formulario` por el nombre de la nueva página con su ruta correcta

Answer (score 0):

En el action en el form no funciona por tener la palabra "formulario" tal cual, hay va el nombre de tu archivo al que quieres redireccionar-le el método POST...

A parte te has dejado el punto división ./ para hacer que cargue desde el mismo directorio donde tienes los archivos.

También hay errores en las etiquetas del form

Suponiendo que tu página a la que le envías el método post se llame "nombre-pagina.html" le va este otro código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Mi pagina web</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="./nombre-pagina.html" method="POST"> 
    <label id="nombreetiqueta">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
    <br>
    <label id="apellidoetiqueta">Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
    <br>
    <label id="Comentarioetiqueta">Comentario</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="Igrese un comentario"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<h1>Esta es mi primera pagina web donde contaré sobre mi vida</h1>
<h2>Esto se tratara sobre historias de mi vida</h2>
<p>En esta biografia hablaré de muchas facetas de mi vida donde pasaré por muchos momentos buenos y malos</p>
<hr>
<h2>Mi infancia</h2>
<p>Todo empezó cuando recién tenia 5 años, <span style="color:blue">era un niño feliz y divertido,</span> que se la pasaba <br>
     divirtiendose con sus jugetes</p>
<!-- Este comentario hablaré como hice mi codigo, lo hice facilmente con unos videos de youtube aprendiendo autonomamente en mi habitación-->
<a target="_BLANK" href="https://www.google.com">Ir a mi instagram</a> <br>
<img src="Foticos/enrabiao.jpg"  width="300" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes varios errores: 1)  Has cambiado el `for` de los `label` por ids que no tienen ningun sentido. El `for` en un `label` es para que el cursor se situe en el input con el id donde apunta el `for`, y eso lo tenia bien. 2) Su pregunta, aunque ambigua en su explicación, es **no me funciona el metido GET**, y lo sigues dejando como POST. 3) ¿Nadie se ha dado cuenta que hay dos `</form>`? 4) No has corregido el `_blanck` (ya que corriges -mal- los `labels` podrias haber visto ese tambien).  5) ¿Su instagram es google? 6) Lo del `./` no lo sabemos, quizas quiere enviarlo a su raiz, no crees?

Comment: Ni el for esta en inputs, ni el </form> esta repetido , no manda nada sea el método GET cómo POST ya que el action esta mal editado, sin tocar su código y señalando-le los puntos corregidos, debería de poder saber en que esta fallando, además con solo la barra / puede tener errores en la dirección a la que manda y yo solo le aviso del fallo...

Comment: No me has entendido, sigo afirmando todo lo que he dicho antes, no lo voy a repetir. Revisa bien cada cosa que he dicho y lo veras. (fijate, por ejemplo, que pone despues de **Comentario**).

Comment: Mírate como funciona el `label` con el `for` aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label  y fíjate que si pulsas sobre el texto del `label` en lugar del boton de radio directamente, este se marca, y eso es gracias al `for`.

Comment: Eso no es lo único que dices, si ese no es el fallo, te comento que sigue estando en el action del <form> que tiene sus dos etiquetas de apertura y cierre, el código que nos ofrece hay, no habla de método get y para ir a la raíz no va con ./  va con ../ tantas veces cómo tenga que saltar de directorios hasta llegar a la raíz

Comment: Tenias razón en las etiquetas form, se había colado una que no había visto en el label

Comment: Bien, esa que acabas de quitar deberias decirlo en la respuesta, pues es la crucial para que el boton empiece a funcionar.

Comment: Y lo del método **get**, si t efijas, solo aparece en el **titulo de la pregunta**, por eso tambien necesitamos su aclaración porque es el OP quien lo pone en la pregunta, pero luego va y nos mete un POST en el form. Eso es inconsistente por su parte y tambien deberiamos ponerlo en una respuesta.

Comment: Esos errores los había pasado por alto, cómo me había centrado en la propiedad del action del <form> no había caído en lo demás

Comment: Lo entiendo, solo quiero que mejores tu respuesta con lo que he visto para que sea valida y le quite el -1, porque no era util realmente, no solucoinaba su problema.

Comment: Bueno, se lo he quitado igualmente aunque esperaba que se lo dijeras en la respuesta, pues no se si va a copiar/pegar tu codigo o solo leer la explicación que le das. En cuanto al _BLANK deberias ponerlo en minusculas. Y si dejas los labels sin los `for` entonces estan perdiendo la funcionalidad que te explicaba antes. Pero bueno, no insistire mas, ahora el boton submit del form se ejecutará, cosa que no pasaba antes.